# Addition of a voltage selector switch for a dual-voltage motor

Tags: voltage, motor, dual

I have a 3hp, single-phase 120V / 220 V, 1750rpm, 184t frame size, compressor-duty motor.

I would like to include a voltage selector switch in the junction box, to select 30A 120 V or 30 A 220 V depending on the voltage available at site.

My dad had a similar setup, factory-configured decades ago. I have attached a picture of the wiring.

I request help to prepare a list of material / parts and a proper circuit diagram.

Comment: Your photo didn't come through. Please try to edit it into your question.